# Orthonormal basis and constructing linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Q: If I have an orthonormal basis {u1,u2,u3} such that u1 = {1,0,i} and I need to construct a map f such that image(f)=Span {(1,0,i)} and any v in kernel(f) with w in the image(f) has an inner product of 0, how would I do so?

I know that inner product of orthonormal vectors is 0 so some of the vectors from my orthonormal basis should be in the kernel and others in the image to complete the latter requirement. As for the image = span{(1,0,i)}, not really sure how to go about that..

Answer (score 0):

The image of the map of the matrix A = (1 1 1)

```
                                   (0 0 0)

                                   (0 0 0)
```

Is the span{(1,0,i)}
Not sure though if that's what you want.